# Deep clone parent and children without using Apex - possible?

Tags: clone

I've seen some tools like Super Clone that can do deep clone (aka clone child records), but what I am looking for is a tool that clones record and then reparents the child records.

I've seen [there are some code examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000093OqIAI), but I am trying to avoid using that before I've asked the community.

Thanks

Comment: There's no OOTB functionality, if that's what you're asking. Use code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved the problem with a little piece of code. I hope it helps you too.

I've renamed references from my org so there might be error here and there, but I think you'll get it. Also, I have no testing class for it.

Here's the extension class code:

```
public class cloneAndReparent {
    Public      List<sobject>           selectedRecords      {get;set;}  
    Public      parent_object__c        newRecord           {get;set;}  


    public cloneAndReparent(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      mycon = controller;
      selectedMeters = mycon.getSelected();
    }
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mycon;
    String recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');


    public PageReference ReparentRecords(){
        parent_object__c recToClone = [select id, name from parent_object__c where (id=:recId) limit 1][0]; // note that you will have to select more fields in order them to be cloned!
        parent_object__c newRecord = recToClone.clone(false, false);
        insert newRecord;

        list <child_object__c> childrenToReparent = [select id from child_object__c where id in: selectedRecords];    
        for (child_object__c child: childrenToReparent){
            child.CUSTOM_RELATIONSHIP_NAME__c=newRecord.id;
        }
        try {
             update childrenToReparent;
        } catch (DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        } 
        PageReference newURL = new PageReference('/'+newRecord.id);
        newURL.setRedirect(true);
        return newURL;        
    }
}
```

And here's Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="parent_object__c" extensions="cloneAndReparent" recordSetVar="records" action="{!ReparentRecords}" >
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that many Detail objects cannot be reparented, and must be deleted and recreated. For example, Attachments cannot have their ParentId changed.

Comment: That mostly applies to standard objects, doesn't it?

Comment: Custom objects may work this way as well, depending on whether there is a Master-Detail relationship and how it is set up. If it's just a simple custom Lookup relationship, there wouldn't normally be a problem with reparenting.

Comment: Just to be clear - there is a checkbox that enables reparenting, regardless of relationship type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at iClone app? IT will allow you to clone child records and re-parent as well. You can do field over-rides as well.

Link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B39tWEAR

Comment: Not free. I wouldn't be comfortable paying more than $1 per month.